# Weird Svelte reactivity behaviour with select box

Tags: svelte

I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong here.
I have a simple child component that receives a list of objects from the parent and uses their name property as options inside select box. I store the selected option in a local variable.
I am watching for props list changes from outside using $: onChange(props) method and when it changes I want to set local variable to the first element in the props array. Like so:

```
<script>
    export let parameters = [];
    
    let selectedParameter;

    function onChange(_){
    selectedParameter = parameters[0];
    }

    $: onChange(parameters);
</script>

<select bind:value={selectedParameter} >
  {#each parameters as param}
    <option value={param}>{param.name}</option>
  {/each}
</select>
```

However, now the select is broken and I cant change the selection because when I try to select another option it triggers my reactivity listener for props, although props didn't change.
Does changing an option inside a select modifies props?

Please help me understand how it work. How do I prevent this behaviour?

Here is the parent component:

```
<script>
    import Select from "./Select.svelte"
    
        let parameters;

    let params1 = [{name: "1-1"}, {name: "1-2"}];
    let params2 = [{name: "2-1"}, {name: "2-2"}];
</script>

<button on:click={()=> parameters=params1}>load parameters 1</button>
<button on:click={()=> parameters=params2}>load parameters 2</button>

<Select {parameters} />
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/248849d0d7c641d1a9fc70cc58b7c527?version=4.2.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Svelte seems to currently [invalidate too much when using `bind:value` on a `<select>`](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/8243); this bit of code is generated:

```js
function select_change_handler() {
    selectedParameter = select_value(this);
    $$invalidate(1, selectedParameter);
    $$invalidate(0, parameters); // <-- this is the problem
}
```

There are various workarounds, one would be to not use a binding. But then you cannot use an object as an option `value` (unless you access the internal property `__value`), the native select `value` is always a string.

E.g.

```html
<!-- Split bind:value into input-only value and on:change -->
<select
    value={selectedParameter}
    on:change={e => selectedParameter = e.target.value}>
    {#each parameters as param}
        <option value={param.name}> <!-- Use a primitive value here -->
            {param.name}
        </option>
    {/each}
</select>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/55f4aa028b32463aa0c1c1856e004997?version=4.2.1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure either why this happens, but as a workaround, you could make it so that the first entry is selected whenever the currently selected item (including nothing) is not in the parameters list:

```
<script>
    export let parameters = [];
    let selectedParameter;

    $: if (!parameters.includes(selectedParameter)) selectedParameter = parameters[0];
</script>

<select bind:value={selectedParameter}>
    {#each parameters as param}
        <option value={param}>{param.name}</option>
    {/each}
</select>
```